# Can we copy the content of an array to another array in languages likes C# and C++

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, dynamic, static

Basically, I have a simple question that I stumbled across.

Code:

```
// Self implementation of
// the Vector Class in C++

#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
template <typename T> class vectorClass
{

// arr is the integer pointer
// which stores the address of our vector
T* arr;

// capacity is the total storage
// capacity of the vector
int capacity;

// current is the number of elements
// currently present in the vector
int current;

   public:
// Default constructor to initialise
// an initial capacity of 1 element and
// allocating storage using dynamic allocation
vectorClass()
{
    arr = new T[1];
    capacity = 1;
    current = 0;
}

// Function to add an element at the last
void push(T data)
{

    // if the number of elements is equal to the
    // capacity, that means we don't have space to
    // accommodate more elements. We need to double the
    // capacity
    if (current == capacity) {
        T* temp = new T[2 * capacity];

        // copying old array elements to new array
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
            temp[i] = arr[i];
        }

        // deleting previous array
        delete[] arr;
        capacity *= 2;
        arr = temp;
    }

    // Inserting data
    arr[current] = data;
    current++;
}

// function to add element at any index
void push(int data, int index)
{

    // if index is equal to capacity then this
    // function is same as push defined above
    if (index == capacity)
        push(data);
    else
        arr[index] = data;
}

// function to extract element at any index
T get(int index)
{

    // if index is within the range
    if (index < current)
        return arr[index];
}

// function to delete last element
void pop() { current--; }

// function to get size of the vector
int size() { return current; }

// function to get capacity of the vector
int getcapacity() { return capacity; }

// function to print array elements
void print()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < current; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
};
```

Question:

1. In the above code, The `Push` method has a statement `arr = temp;` What does that statement mean?
   Is it that they are trying to copy the content of array temp to arr?
2. What if the `arr` is of static type? Would simply copying the content of one array to another array like this work? Or will it work with dynamic array?
3. Would it work the same in programming language such a C#?

Comment: 1. It's a pointer re-assignment. 2. ? 3. I don't know enough about C#, but you likely don't write containers in that language.

Comment: *"Is it that they are trying to copy the content of array temp to arr?"* -- Since `arr` is not an array, where would those contents go? (Don't think about how `arr` was initialized. Think about that part of the code in isolation. You assign something to a `T*` variable and suddenly there has to be a destination array?)

Answer (score 2):

In C++ we need to manage the dynamic memory, it's different with C#

> 1. In the above code, The Push method has a statement arr = temp; What does that statement mean? Is it that they are trying to copy the content of array temp to arr?

It just means copy the pointer temp to arr, no array copy happened here. It's a type of ownership transfer, the dynamic memory handled by temp has been transferred to arr.

> 2. What if the arr is of static type? Would simply copying the content of one array to another array like this work? Or will it work with a dynamic array?

What do you mean by `static type`? All variables in C++ have a static type, all arrays need to be explicitly copied by using `memcpy` or `std::copy`. You may also have a look at the `std::vector` [container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), in C++ we don't use dynamic arrays too often, your code isn't modern C++ style, we prefer to use containers other than manager dynamic arrays (This keep us away from memory leaking, some kinds of memory corruption). We can use the `=` to copy vectors, it's much easier to use and safer.

> 3. Would it work the same in a programming language such a C#?

For C# you can reference this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070530/copy-arrays-to-array). In addition to not needing to manage memory, to some extent, it is similar to C++.