# Adding an array property into an array of another object

Tags: c#

I have this call that returns an array of treatments

```
 var procedures = await client.GetProceduresAsync(clinicId);
```

I was trying to loop and insert all procedureIds (from the array) into an array property of the availableSlotsQuery

```
var availableSlotsQuery = new AvailableSlotsQuery();
            foreach (var procedure in procedures.Select(x=> x.Procedure))
            {
                availableSlotsQuery = new AvailableSlotsQuery
                {
                    ClinicId = clinicId,
                    ProcedureIds = new [] { procedure.Id},
                    Start = request.From.ToDateTimeOffset(),
                    End = request.To.ToDateTimeOffset(),
                    CaregiverId = therapistId?.Id
                };
            }
```

This is not working.

ProcedureIds is a string [] but after looping I only have one id in the ProcedureIds property

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you edit your snippet to be a [mcve]?

Comment: Looks like your creating an object each time you do the loop overriding the values each time

Comment: @MarkDavies yes, I think this is the issue, however how should I add to the existing array?

Comment: What array? and why not use a List?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy Arrays to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070530/copy-arrays-to-array)

Comment: I think you need to remove the loop and instead use this : `ProcedureIds = procedures.Select(x=> x.Procedure.Id).ToArray(),`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with looping

```
var availableSlotsQuery = new AvailableSlotsQuery();
availableSlotsQuery = new AvailableSlotsQuery
{
    ClinicId = clinicId,
    Start = request.From.ToDateTimeOffset(),
    End = request.To.ToDateTimeOffset(),
    CaregiverId = therapistId?.Id
};

var listOfProcedureIds = new List<string>();
foreach (var procedure in procedures.Select(x=> x.Procedure))
{
    listOfProcedureIds.Add(procedure.Id);
}

availableSlotsQuery.ProcedureIds = listOfProcedureIds.ToArray();
```

without looping

```
availableSlotsQuery = new AvailableSlotsQuery
{
    ClinicId = clinicId,
    Start = request.From.ToDateTimeOffset(),
    End = request.To.ToDateTimeOffset(),
    CaregiverId = therapistId?.Id,
    ProcedureIds = procedures.Select(x => x.Procedure.Id).ToArray()
};
```

as mentioned by all, you are creating a new `object` in your `foreach` statement

```
foreach (var procedure in procedures.Select(x=> x.Procedure))
{
//as you can see here with the availableSlotQuery = new AvailableSlotQuery
   availableSlotsQuery = new AvailableSlotsQuery
   {
   //properties
   };
}
```